# regexp with pcre in C how match all pattern?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

i have  create a script in C with PCRE in linux , for match a word in a string , it work, but now i  want modify it  because i want  it match , all same word inside a phrases, for do that i do this  mod. but  return me warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pcre_get_substring’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
, sorry i am a beginner programmer in C , come one can give me a solution with explain ? thanks

````
*   gcc -Wall pcre1.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib -lpcre
*   or
*   gcc -Wall pcre1.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib  -lpcre   
*   or
*   gcc pcre1.c -lpcre   
*/     
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pcre.h>               
#define OVECCOUNT 30    /* should be a multiple of 3 */
#define EBUFLEN 128            
#define BUFLEN 1024           
        
int main()
{               
        pcre *re;
        const char *error;
        int erroffset;
        int ovector[OVECCOUNT];
        int rc, i;
int offsetcount;
int offsets[(0+1)*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
char *result;
        char src[] = "111 <title>Hello World</title> <title>Hello World</title>222";
        char pattern[] = "<title>(.*)</title>";
        re = pcre_compile(pattern, 0, &error, &erroffset, NULL);
        if (re == NULL) {
                printf("PCRE compilation failed at offset %d: %s/n", erroffset, error);
                return 1;
        }
offsetcount = pcre_exec(re, NULL, src, strlen(src), 0, 0, offsets, (0+1)*3);
    while (offsetcount > 0) {
        if (pcre_get_substring(src, &offsets, offsetcount, 0, &result) >= 0) {
            // Do something with match we just stored into result
            printf("de %s/n",result);
        }
        offsetcount = pcre_exec(re, NULL, src, strlen(src), 0, offsets[1], offsets, (0+1)*3);
    } 
        free(re);
        return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `&offsets` should just be `offsets`, because `offsets` is already a pointer/array.

Comment: i  remove  &offsets to -> offsets   and &result -> result   because giveme  the same error , but now  tell me warning: passing argument 5 of ‘pcre_get_substring’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   63 |         if (pcre_get_substring(src, offsets, offsetcount, 0, result) >= 0) {
      |                                                              ^~~~~~
      |                                                              |
      |                                                              char *

Comment: `(const char **) &result`

Comment: thanks it  work, i have also some questions , sorry again , 1.(const char **) &result  is  a cast of pointer ??? i understund good?  2.  if i want print result i insert ```  if (pcre_get_substring(src, offsets, offsetcount, 0, (const char **) &result) >= 0) {
            printf("de %s/n", &result);
        }```  but return me error ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘const char **’

Comment: Yes, it's a cast. The type of the 5th argument to `pcre_get_substring` must be `const char **`. Just use `result` with `printf`, not `&result`.  Change the pattern to `"<title>.*</title>"` if you want to see something printed, as your code will not print capture group content as it is.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```c
#include <pcre.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
          
#define OFFSETCOUNT 6    // (capturing_group_count + 1) * 3
          
int main() {
    const char *error;
    int erroffset;
    int offsetcount;
    int offsets[OFFSETCOUNT];
    const char *result;

    char src[] = "<title>One</title> <title>Two</title> <title>Three</title> <title>Four</title> <title>Five</title>";
    char pattern[] = "<title>(.*?)</title>";

    pcre *re = pcre_compile(pattern, 0, &error, &erroffset, NULL);
    if (re == NULL) {
        printf("PCRE compilation failed at offset %d: %s/n", erroffset, error);
        return 1;
    }

    offsets[1] = 0;
    while ((offsetcount = pcre_exec(re, NULL, src, strlen(src), offsets[1], 0, offsets, OFFSETCOUNT)) >= 0) { 
        if (pcre_get_substring(src, offsets, offsetcount, 1, &result) >= 0) {
            printf("%s\n", result);
            pcre_free_substring(result);
        }
    } 
    
    free(re);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Aside from the type errors, the main problem with your code is the use of `(0+1)*3` instead of `OVECCOUNT` or at least `6`, as you are using a regex with one capturing group.

You also needed to add a `?` to your regex to make `.*` match 'lazily', i.e. as few times as possible, otherwise `.*` will greedily match from `"<title>"` right up to the last `"</title>"`.

Also, you were passing `0` to `pcre_get_substring` which gets the full match, rather than `1` which gets the match of the first capture group.

Comment: infinity thanks so much @MikeM

Comment: but for better result (i read   in help of PCRE ) for my case for have  a list of matching , i should use pcre_get_substring_list  ??  is much faster ? thanks

Comment: @RubensBarrichello77 `pcre_get_substring_list` wouldn't be any faster. It does not give all the matches, it just produces a list of the substrings matched by a single `pcre_exec` call. If used in the example above it would just produce a list of two items each time it is called: the full match and a single capture group match. If all the matches are required `pcre_exec` would still have to be called repeatedly as above. BTW You should really be using PCRE2, as PCRE is now "at end of life".

Comment: thanks  for reply and  good year , ok i understund , for use pcre2  i change include ? and  rest of  your script (for example )  remaning  the same ? or is  compleatly  different ??  thanks again